# How to change the keyboard language (two languages setup) at login screen on Macbook Air 13?

Tags: password, login, language

During login I had two keyboard language options which appeared on the right top corner which I could choose.  After reboot, I lost them.  How can I get those two keyboard language options again? I need to access one of them for a special character in my password which would allow me to get in. Otherwise, the system cannot verify my password.

Comment: Once you are logged in, the instructions are at  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-users-groups-login-options-preferences-mtusr005/mac

Comment: What exactly is the special character you need?  It may be available somewhere on the keyboard which you do have available.  What is that, US?